Finding objects with tags vs Layers vs Scripts in Unity?
I never know which one I should use. If a bullet flies towards a target, let's say a zombie, should the Zombie have a tag? Maybe an "enemy" tag, or "Damage" tag? Or should I look for a layer, that also works. But most games I make that have things that can die usually share an interface, an "IDamageable" interface. So the bullet could look for GameObjects that uses that interface.
So how do you know which one is "correct"?
(1)I have heard that people dislike using Tags because it uses strings, so maybe not tags.
(2)I don't know much about layers except it decides what renders over what(or that's sorting layer in 2D. I dont know what just "layers" really are, but I do know that they seperate things). You can create different layers and decide what layer interacts with what.
(3) You can create interactions based on the scripts different objects have
So how do you which one to use? Are there any online tutorials you can follow to learn this?

Your understanding of layers is incorrect. See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html . Questions about which tutorials to follow are considered off-topic. The rest of your question is unclear. Under what circumstances are you trying to find an object? Is your bullet looking for objects every frame (it shouldn't do this), or only when it collides with something?

(1) First of all, what do you mean my understanding of layers are wrong? I said that they are used for rendering and collision and the Unity link you provided also said that? (2)Where are you even supposed to get any help regarding what tutorials or courses you should follow. Every site its always "Of topic". Everyone always seems to know everything, but when you ask them how they got so good at Unity they can't tell you, why is that? I can tell you what I did and didn't do, so why can't anyone else? All I need is a little push in a direction, it doesn't have to be the right one, just a push.

(3) "Under what circumstances are you trying to find an object? " well it depends. If its a bullet then I would use OntriggerEnter/OnCollisionEnter. But that doesnt answer my question. I still have to choose between finding an object with tag, layer or script in this situation. Or lets say you a have a turret that looks for targets inside an area with "Physics.OverlapBox". You can either find the objects by layer or use an if statement to see if the colliders you find have a specific tag/class. So once again, which of the three should you use?

There is no correct or incorrect way to do this. Only ways that work for you or don't work for you.
But personally I don't like tags. The main problem is that when you create a more complex game with many separate game mechanics, then you will sooner or later run into situations where different game mechanics require a different tag on the same game object. But you can only have one tag on an object. So this is going to get ugly. Which is why I usually don't make use of tags at all.
My favorite paradigm is that of duck typing. The idea behind duck typing is "If it quacks like a duck and walks like a duck, it's a duck". Or in Unity terms:
if(other.TryGetComponent<Quacking>(out var quacking) && 
   other.TryGetComponent<Walking>(out var walking) 
{
    Debug.log("Collided with a duck");
    quacking.quack();
    walking.stop();
}

The nice thing about the duck typing paradigm is that it makes your architecture very flexible. If you want an object to be able to interact with a certain game mechanic, then you just need to add the components that are required by that mechanic and it just works.

I'd second this: I prefer checking by component in most cases, since usually I don't just want to match an object, I want to do something with it, and the component reference gives me access to its specific properties and capabilities — same motivation as using FindAnyObjectByType vs FindObjectByTag. For collision checks and range queries specifically though, I'll often also use physics layers to filter out as many of the irrelevant objects as possible, to minimize processing load and only invoke my code for objects that might have the component I want.
